# Probability of of your hand contains at least one other ace among $13$ cards?

Tags: probability

If a set of $52$ cards are distributed among $4$ people where each person has $13$ cards, what is the probability that your hand contains at least one other ace? (it is already known that you have at least one ace)

Comment: Hey and welcome to MSE! What are your own thoughts about this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? People will be more likely to answer your question if they can see you have put in some effort yourself first

Comment: I tried using the idea of conditional probability i.e. P(A|B)=P(A∩B)/P(B) so P(A|B)=(number of ways to have at least 2 aces)/ (number of ways to have at least 1 ace). I can find both the numerator and denominator but I am just unsure if my logic is correct

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Find: $$P(A\geq2\mid A\geq1)=\frac{P(A\geq2)}{P(A\geq1)}$$where $A$ denotes the number of aces in your hand.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought about this method but I was just confused about what P(A∩B) should be but I later realised it is just the number of ways to have at least two aces

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with calculation.

Comment: Is the probability change after each time a card distributed?

Answer (score 0):

You get to select 12 cards among 51 (you have one ace already), of which 3 are aces...